# Migrating from Eclipse to Android studio. How can I use existed ant file 'build.xml'

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, ant, android-ndk

I migrate my eclipse projects to Android studio projects. Everything works on well with me but only ant autobuild.
In my previous eclipse projects we use the embeded ant builder. Also we creates ant file 'build.xml' like below:

```
<!-- define several const variables -->
<property file="local.properties" />
<property file="ant.properties" />
<property name="classes.dir" value="bin/classes" />
<property name="jar.dir" value="bin" />
<property name="config.dir" value="src/com/naver/mediacasting/sdk/config" />
<property name="config.dest.dir" value="com/naver/mediacasting/sdk/config" />
<property name="neptune.dir" value="../../../../Library/Neptune/Build/Targets/arm-android-linux" />
<property name="httpmediaserver.dir" value = "../../../../Library/HttpMediaServer/project/android" />
<property name="naverlink.dir" value="../../../../DLNA/src/NaverLink/project/android" />
<property name="naverlogger.dir" value = "../../../../Library/Logger/project/android" />
<property name="m3u8manager.dir" value = "../../../../Library/StreamProxyConverter/project/android" />
<property name="naverair.dir" value = "../../../../Airplay/src/NaverAir/project/android" />



<property environment="env" />
<condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
    <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
</condition>

<loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />


<fail
        message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
        unless="sdk.dir"
/>

<condition property="ndk.dir" value="${env.NDK_ROOT}">
    <isset property="env.NDK_ROOT" />
</condition>

<fail
        message="ndk.dir is missing. Please set the NDK_ROOT windows environment variable to your NDK path."
        unless="ndk.dir"
/>


<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />


<import file="../../../../Apps/Android/src/MediaCastingAndroidApp/ant/bin/build.xml" />


<target name="-pre-compile">
<echo message="JARPATH=${toString:project.all.jars.path}"></echo>

<path id="google-support">
    <path path="${toString:project.all.jars.path}"></path>
    <pathelement location="../../tools/mediarouter/appcompat/bin/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar"></pathelement>
    <pathelement location="../../tools/mediarouter/mediarouter/bin/android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar"></pathelement>
    <pathelement location="../../tools/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar"></pathelement>
</path>

<path id="project.all.jars.path">
    <path refid="google-support"></path>
</path>

<echo message="JARPATH=${toString:project.all.jars.path}"></echo>
</target>


<!-- default java builder will not copy none class file in to classes folder, 
so this target to is used to copy configuration xml files into classes folder before package to jar file -->
<target name="copy_config">
    <echo message="${classes.dir}/${config.dir}"/>
    <echo message="${jar.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}/${config.dest.dir}" />
     <copy todir="${classes.dir}/${config.dest.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${config.dir}"/>
    </copy>
</target>

<!-- Package several jar files togeter -->
<target name="package_jar">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
     <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar">
         <zipfileset src="${jar.dir}/classes.jar" />
         <zipfileset src="libs/nelo2-android-sdk-common-0.9.0.jar"/>
         <zipfileset src="libs/nelo2-android-sdk-https-0.9.0.jar"/>
         <zipfileset src="libs/nelo2-android-sdk-thrift-0.9.0.jar"/>
         <zipfileset src="../../../../Chromecast/src/Android/bin/classes.jar" />
     </jar>
</target>

<!--  Call ndk-build.cmd to do native build clean -->
<target name="ndk-build-clean">
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd" failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${naverlink.dir}" />
        <arg value = "clean" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd" failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${httpmediaserver.dir}" />
        <arg value = "clean" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd " failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${neptune.dir}" />
        <arg value = "clean" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd " failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${naverlogger.dir}" />
        <arg value = "clean" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd " failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${m3u8manager.dir}" />
        <arg value = "clean" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd " failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${naverair.dir}" />
        <arg value = "clean" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd " failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "clean" />  
    </exec>


</target>

<target name="del-crunch">
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="../../../../Chromecast/tools/mediarouter/appcompat/bin/res/crunch" />
    </delete>
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="../../../../Chromecast/tools/mediarouter/mediarouter/bin/res/crunch" />
    </delete>
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="../../../../Chromecast/tools/google-play-services_lib/bin/res/crunch" />
    </delete>
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="../../../../Chromecast/src/Android/bin/res/crunch" />
    </delete>
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="./bin/res/crunch" />
    </delete>
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="../../../../Chromecast/tools/google-play-services_lib/bin/res/crunch" />
    </delete>
</target>

<!--  Call ndk-build.cmd to build several other native libraries -->
<target name="ndk-build">


    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd" failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${neptune.dir}" />
    </exec>

    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd " failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${naverair.dir}" />
    </exec>

    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd" failonerror="true">
         <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${naverlink.dir}" />
    </exec>

    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd" failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${httpmediaserver.dir}" />
    </exec>

    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd" failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${naverlogger.dir}" />
    </exec>

    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd" failonerror="true">
        <arg value = "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${m3u8manager.dir}" />
    </exec>


    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd" failonerror="true">
    </exec>
</target>

<!-- Build release version of SDK -->
<target name="java_build" depends="clean, release, copy_config">
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}android.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>   
</target>


<!-- as description  -->
<target description="copy genearted jar and .so to application project" depends="del-crunch,ndk-build,debug,copy_config, package_jar" name="copy-lib">
     <mkdir dir="../../../../release/deploy/sdk/libs/armeabi" />
     <mkdir dir="../../../../release/deploy/sdk/symbol" />
     <delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
        <fileset dir="../../../../release/deploy/sdk/libs/armeabi"/>
    </delete>
    <copy todir="../../../../release/deploy/sdk/libs/armeabi">
        <fileset dir="libs/armeabi"/>
    </copy>

<delete file="../../../../release/deploy/sdk/License_MediaCastingSDK_Android.txt"/>
    <copy tofile="../../../../release/deploy/sdk/License_MediaCastingSDK_Android.txt">
        <fileset file ="License_MediaCastingSDK_Android.txt"/>
    </copy> 

    <delete file="../../../../release/deploy/sdk/libs/${ant.project.name}Android.jar"/>
    <copy tofile="../../../../release/deploy/sdk/libs/${ant.project.name}Android.jar">
        <fileset file ="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
    </copy>  

    <delete file="../../../../release/deploy/sdk/symbol/libnaverlink_jni.so"/>
    <copy todir="../../../../release/deploy/sdk/symbol">
        <fileset file ="${jar.dir}/../obj/local/armeabi/libnaverlink_jni.so"/>
    </copy>  
</target>
```

This is just one 'build.xml' in one sub project. In fact we have several subproject and each of them have it's own 'build.xml'. It's a big project, and ant is used to automatic generate the .so and .jar. Finally copy to the main project \libs .

My problem is when migrating to android studio. There is no embeded ant builder. And the NDK files .so and .jar will not automatically created by running 'build.xml'. 
So, in AS, what should I do to run the 'build.xml' of each subproject? the procedures will be much appreciated. Also, Is it possible to run 'build.xml' s as a whole and automatically in AS.
I said to much because it is a little complex. Thanks for your patients of reading this. Also your help is welcome. Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried running your ant build from the command line?

Comment: Not yet. Sounds good idea.

Comment: You can call Ant directly from Gradle: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html